# Generate reports on agent per environment in UDeploy

Tags: java, groovy, udeploy, urbancode

We have a requirement to generate reports on agents per application /Environment in UDeploy

Do we have an API from Udeploy for this ?

Do we have any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There are some basic reports provided with the product, but they do not provide that info:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.2/com.ibm.udeploy.doc/topics/reports_ch.html

You may be able to get the info you need from the API:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.2/com.ibm.udeploy.reference.doc/topics/rest_api_ref_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try by first getting base resources list using rest

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.1.3/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/rest_cli_environment_getbaseresources_get.html

the response is a json file . we can query the json file further down to know status of agents